# How to size a picture automatically

Tags: html

Is there a way with HTML that I can auto re-size a picture without having to look at the resolution of the picture and changing the height and width manually?

Here is what I have so far,

```
<img src = "jack bauers.jpg" width ="562" height ="358"/>
```

Comment: Re-size it to what exactly? You can use javascript to check it's width and height and increase it by a fixed ratio.

Comment: Try something like this: `<img src="jack bauers.jpg" style="width:50%;height:50%">` It'll change the images height and width to 50% of their original values.

Comment: Just leave out either the width or height and the browser will scale the image proportionately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img src="smth" width=123></img>
```

Then browser'll calculate the height automatically.

```
<img src="smth" height=123></img>
```

Then width will be chosen automatically.

```
<img src="smth" height="45%"></img>
```

and

```
<img src="smth" width="45%"></img>
```

Can be explained using the browser's smartness too :)

Comment: You're answer is correct (at least if this is what @JackBauers is asking for. You should add some explanation though.

Comment: @Cfreak, I've just added it. You see

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want resize accoding too outer `<div>` the do

```
<img src=""  style="max-height:100%;max-width:100%"></img>
```

dont use width height

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/singhakash07/xwrvxser/785/)